# Getting error in Regex expression value to pull a value from logs

Tags: regex, kubernetes, automation, scripting

I have a regex value where I am trying to make change so that it will give labels value also from the below logs. regex value is returning me pod name , namespace and container info, but along with this I also need to pull app value from (labels) section. which is **drupal-ms-brands-funyuns-qa**

Regex:
`(?<tag>[^.]+)?\.?(?<pod_name>[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*)_(?<namespace_name>[^_]+)_(?<container_name>.+)-(?<docker_id>[a-z0-9]{64})\.log$`

LOGS:

```
 "kubernetes"=>{​​​​​​​"pod_name"=>"drupal-ms-brands-funyuns-qa766f4ff-wn9", "namespace_name"=>"web-system", "pod_id"=>"pod-name", "labels"=>{​​​​​​​"app"=>"drupal-ms-brands-funyuns-qa", "chart"=>"drupal-ms-brands-funyuns-qa", "istio.io/rev"=>"default"}​​​​​​​, "annotations"=>{​​​​​​​"kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container"=>"drupal-ms-brands-funyuns-qa", "kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-logs-container"=>"drupal-ms-brands-funyuns-qa", "kubernetes.io/psp"=>"eks.privileged", "prometheus.io/path"=>"/stats/prometheus", "prometheus.io/port"=>"15020", "prometheus.io/scrape"=>"true", "sidecar.istio.io/status"=>"{​​​​​​​"initContainers":["istio-init"],"containers":["istio-proxy"],"volumes":["istio-envoy","istio-data","istio-podinfo","istio-token","istiod-ca-cert"],"imagePullSecrets":null}​​​​​​​"}​​​​​​​, "host"=>"ip-10-2-86-151.ec2.internal", "container_name"=>"istio-proxy", "docker_id"=>"52d054c501afc6c741d528648712684612846842788742155e824cbef13041b5bdfd11f", "container_hash"=>"isfgkh/proxyv2@sha256:a78b7a1355345347c34e02d6b4355aaf8fe2a2c75914821423bdf764e8", "container_image"=>"istio/proxyv2:4.22.4"}​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​]
```

Looking forward for an advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question: which tool exactly are you using for regex, how current output looks and how expected output should look?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am working on kubernetes logs, where with regex expression I want to get the output values for pod name, namespace and container info. Now i have to make the change in the regex expression so that it will get the app value from the label section in the logs. You can check the log that I have provided where i want to fetch the "app"=>"drupal-ms-brands-funyuns-qa"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me clarify my question - where and how do you exactly using this regex expresion? I tried to use it some online websites, like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but there is always `no match` information.